# I have ORA-01756 error using ojdbc7.jar in Tomcat

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, ojdbc

A few weeks ago I started having this error in my connections from tomcat to Oracle:

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Locale not recognized`

Trying the following configurations in the jvm didn't seem to fix it:

`-Duser.language=es -Duser.region=ES`

so I contacted Oracle support and they provided me with the patch p30649766_121020

After applying it, the error is considerably smaller and has disappeared, with the following error appearing instead:
 `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: se ha producido un error a nivel 1 de SQL recursivo  ORA-01756: la cadena entrecomillada no está terminada correctamente`

From oracle do not locate the error.

I have tried to reproduce the error directly with some of the queries but without success.

What I have achieved is, by means of a network capture, to see that when the error occurs, the following string appears:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE='Europe/MadridSESSION_CLIENT_LOBATTR1SESSION_CLIENT_DRIVER_NAMEjdbcthin
```

And when done correctly, I see the following:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE='Europe/Madrid' NLS_LANGUAGE='SPANISH'  NLS_TERRITORY='SPAIN'SESSION_CLIENT_LOBATTR1SESSION_CLIENT_DRIVER_NAMEjdbcthin
```

In the first string a quotation mark is missing. It is not something that I have managed to reproduce directly, since the error is random.

It seems to be a problem with the driver since it is a query launched by the driver before the query launched by my application. Has this happened to anyone before?

After one of the comments of this post, I tried to user another versions of the driver:

```
java -jar ojdbc8.jar Oracle 19.22.0.0.0 JDBC 4.2 compiled with javac 1.8.0_391 on Sun_Oct_29_03:24:04_PDT_2023 

java -jar ojdbc8.jar 
Oracle 23.3.0.23.09 JDBC 4.2 debug compiled with javac 1.8.0_381-ea on Thu_Aug_31_22:00:13_PDT_2023

[Default Properties Resource]
#Default Connection Properties Resource
#Thu Mar 14 10:09:03 CET 2024
```

I have the same error, seems to be less frequently.

My oracle version is: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0

Tomcat: 8.5

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the code that generates that error. The English error message is `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: An error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01756: Quoted string is not properly terminated` so you need to terminate the quoted string - however we cannot tell you where as you have not shared any code.

Comment: What's the version of the driver? "java -jar ojdbc7.jar" will give you an answer. This looks like a driver bug that would most likely be fixed in the most recent release update of 19c: 19.22. So my recommendation would be to just upgrade to that. It supports the 12.1.0.2 DB.

Comment: The driver version is:

Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 JDBC 4.1 compiled with JDK7 on Mon_Jun_30_11:30:34_PDT_2014

I saw that but in doc sais that its not compatible with java 1.8. My java`s version is:

java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)

Comment: we use the driver that you indicated in the previous comment:

java -jar ojdbc8.jar 
Oracle 19.22.0.0.0 JDBC 4.2 compiled with javac 1.8.0_391 on Sun_Oct_29_03:24:04_PDT_2023

we have the same error but with less frequency